# Optimizing a query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

Here's my current query:

```
select i.id, i.alder, i.kon, i.artal, i.vecka, s.fraga, s.varumarke, 
       part1.JokerinText, part2.LotonText, part3.VikingText, 
       part4.VedonlyönninText, part5.KenonText 

from intervjuperson i

inner join svar s on s.intervjuperson = i.id

left join (select s2.text as LotonText, s2.intervjuperson 
         from svar s2 where s2.fraga = 97607) as part2 on part2.intervjuperson = i.id

left join (select s2.text as VikingText, s2.intervjuperson 
         from svar s2 where s2.fraga = 97608) as part3 on part3.intervjuperson = i.id

left join (select s2.text as jokerinText, s2.intervjuperson 
         from svar s2 where s2.fraga = 97609) as part1 on part1.intervjuperson = i.id

left join (select s2.text as VedonlyönninText, s2.intervjuperson 
         from svar s2 where s2.fraga = 97610) as part4 on part4.intervjuperson = i.id

left join (select s2.text as KenonText, s2.intervjuperson 
         from svar s2 where s2.fraga = 97611) as part5 on part5.intervjuperson = i.id

where s.fraga in (97606) and i.artal > 2010
```

How do I optimize this query so that it takes a few seconds, as currently it is taking 2 minutes?

Comment: Is this MySql or SQL Server?

Comment: could you please format your code? Also, what are the indexes you have defined? did you check the execution plan for the bottle neck?

Comment: Try removing the sub-selects - you can add the sub-select`s where clauses to the LEFT JOIN`s clauses. This might help, it depends on what indexes you have and the size of the tables as to how the optimiser will handle this.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 4):

First check for missing indexes on the table `svar`.

It should be indexed by `fraga` and `intervjuperson` fields. If it is SQL Server, check "Display estimated execution plan" in SQL Management studio with this query open - it will show you, what index could improve your query. Ideal would be one index composed of both `fraga` and `intervjuperson` columns.

Your query could be eventually rewritten like this.

```
select i.id, i.alder, i.kon, i.artal, i.vecka, s.fraga, s.varumarke, 
       part1.text as JokerinText, part2.text as LotonText, part3.text as VikingText, 
       part4.text as VedonlyönninText, part5.text as KenonText 
from intervjuperson i
inner join svar s on s.intervjuperson = i.id
left join svar as part2 on part2.intervjuperson = i.id AND part2.fraga = 97607
left join svar as part3 on part3.intervjuperson = i.id AND part3.fraga = 97608
left join svar as part1 on part1.intervjuperson = i.id AND part1.fraga = 97609
left join svar as part4 on part4.intervjuperson = i.id AND part4.fraga = 97610
left join svar as part5 on part5.intervjuperson = i.id AND part5.fraga = 97611
where s.fraga in (97606) and i.artal > 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that id is the primary key of table intervjuperson, and columns intervjuperson plus fraga make the primary key for table svar, so all your left joins give you one or zero records per intervjuperson?

Then you can left outer join just once instead and use CASE constructs in your SELECT clause to get the values you are interested in.

```
select 
  i.id, i.alder, i.kon, i.artal, i.vecka, 
  s.fraga, s.varumarke,
  case when parts.fraga = 97609 then parts.text end as JokerinText, 
  case when parts.fraga = 97607 then parts.text end as LotonText, 
  case when parts.fraga = 97608 then parts.text end as VikingText, 
  case when parts.fraga = 97610 then parts.text end as VedonlyönninText, 
  case when parts.fraga = 97611 then parts.text end as KenonText 
from intervjuperson i
inner join svar s on s.intervjuperson = i.id
left join svar as parts on parts.intervjuperson = i.id
where s.fraga in (97606) and i.artal > 2010
group by i.id, s.fraga;
```

You tagged your question both MySQL and SQL Server. Above query is for MySQL. In other dbms it is mandatory that each column in the SELECT clause is either an aggregation or part of the GROUP BY clause. For such a dbms you would have to change `i.alder` to `MIN(i.alder)` or MAX for that matter or have `i.alder` in the GROUP BY clause. The CASE constructs would have to be aggregated, too:

```
select 
  i.id, min(i.alder) as alder, min(i.kon) as kon, min(i.artal) as artal, min(i.vecka) as vecka, 
  s.fraga, min(s.varumarke) as varumarke,
  min(case when parts.fraga = 97609 then parts.text end) as JokerinText, 
  min(case when parts.fraga = 97607 then parts.text end) as LotonText, 
  min(case when parts.fraga = 97608 then parts.text end) as VikingText, 
  min(case when parts.fraga = 97610 then parts.text end) as VedonlyönninText, 
  min(case when parts.fraga = 97611 then parts.text end) as KenonText 
from intervjuperson i
inner join svar s on s.intervjuperson = i.id
left join svar as parts on parts.intervjuperson = i.id
where s.fraga in (97606) and i.artal > 2010
group by i.id, s.fraga;
```

EDIT: I just noticed: you may want to add `and parts.fraga in (97607,97608,97609,97610,97611)` to the left join's ON clause for performance reasons. This doesn't alter the results, but may speed up the join.